# Instagram Endpoint /media/search returns no data. Code: 200

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am playing around with the Instagram api but I am stucked with the media/search endpoint:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=53.549563&lng=9.962584&distance=5&access_token=123456789.7d5423491.423424466ff234gea858ad8c24325e7c7g
```

Problem: I don't get any results for any given location. I have no ideas whats wrong here?

```
{
  "data": [],
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your distance code is very small `&distance=5` is `5 meters` in the instagram API, not `km` but `m` try increasing this to `500` which is the default or `750` which is the max.

Also remember that this is a search on the users behalf of public content so you need that scope.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/

Comment: Okay now I get some of my own images. I'd like to see public data of course. Is this a sandbox issue?

Comment: yes, in sandbox you will only see your data, so it expected to be `[ ]` in sandbox mode

Comment: Mhmm… I am still in dev mode and far away from official review. I also need public data to test my concept. Is there any workaround? Any tipps for the review?

Comment: It's just a server-side search engine. So it is not designed to sign in with another instagram account. I need some kind of application access token.

Comment: No such thing as an "application access token." Sounds like your use case isn't going to fit into one of the 3 valid use cases. You might want to stop wasting your time developing something that Instagram won't ever allow you to use their API for. Read the documentation thoroughly. Especially: https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/